# counting integers in an array and store the count in another

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to count the integers of an array and store the count of those integers in another array.

The code counts the occurrence of an integer but continues to count the rest of the different integers with out resting the count. The code stores only the count of the first integer occurrence without an issue.

My problem is the count doesn't reset when the loop hits the next integer and continues to count from the last integers count and displays that.

How can I improve my code to find the integer occurrences of each individual integer?

```
public count() {
    int k[] = {1,1,2,2};
    int t[] = {0,0,0,0,0};
    int count = 0;
    System.out.println("reset count: "+count);

    for (int f = 0; f<k.length; f++) {
        for (int i =1; i < k.length-1; i++) {
            for (int g = 0; g < t.length; g++ ) {
                if (k[f] == i) {
                    count++;
                    System.out.println("Integer = "+i);
                    System.out.println("count: "+count);
                    t[g] = count;
                }
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
    for (int o = 0; o < t.length; o++) {
        System.out.println("Stored int counts t" + o + " = " + t[o]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you *know* what is the biggest possible element in `k` (lets suppose 100), then you can solve it linearly:

```
int[] t = new int[101]; //subject of change
for (int i : k) {
   t[i]++;
}
```

Here, you'll increase the value of the `i`-th element of `k` when the currently processed element from `k` has value of `i`.

Otherwise, if you don't know the biggest possible element of `k` (and respectively, you won't know how to initialize the `t` array), you can use a `Map`:

```
Map<Integer, Integer> map = new TreeMap<>();
for (int i : k) {
   if (map.containsKey(i)) {
      int value = map.get(i);
      map.put(i, ++value);
   } else {
      map.put(i, 1);
   }
}

for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    int i = entry.getKey();
    int n = entry.getValue();
    System.out.println("The number " + i + " was found " + n + " times.");
}
```

Comment: Using a map instead of the array lifts the restriction of knowing the max element and you can build the array once the processing is done.

Comment: @Dragos.Cojocari, just updated the answer with the alternative (`Map`) approach.

Comment: Ah I see didn't think to use a for each loop. I'll try using a `Map`  as well, appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the HashMap to keep unique values as key, and in iterations check if that key already exists, if it does then increment its value else move on.

Hope this will help.